# RadioButton tkinter : string indices must be integers

Tags: python, tkinter, radio-button

I just want to create a class that shows and handles some `RadioButtons`.
I'm new in `Tkinter` and I don't understand which is the problem.

When I run it, the error says :

```
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2567, in _setup
    name = cnf['name']
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

I think I'm not handling in the right way data in "modes" but is just a feeling.
This is the code:

```
from tkinter import Checkbutton, Radiobutton, StringVar, Tk, Label, IntVar

class Enabler:
    b1: Radiobutton
    b2: Radiobutton
    v: StringVar

    def __init__(self, tk: Tk, r: int, c: int):
        Label(tk, " username/email and password required?").grid(row=r, column=c)
        var = StringVar(tk, "active")
        var.set("active")
        modes = [
            ("Yes", "active"),
            ("No", "disabled")
        ]
        tmp_c: int = c
        for k, v in modes:
            Radiobutton(tk, text=k, value=v, variable=var,
                        command=self.getValue).grid(row=r, column=tmp_c)
            tmp_c += 1

    def getValue(self) -> str:
        print(self.v.get())
        return self.v.get()


tk = Tk()
e = Enabler(tk, 0, 0)
```

I'm using python3.10

Comment: You need to specify `text=" username/email and password required?"` in `Label(tk, " username/email and password required?").grid(row=r, column=c)`

Comment: I feel so stupid